# Script Tag not accepting in Management Center

Tags: websphere-commerce

script tag is not accepting in wcs7 management center in E-mail activity content, how to achieve this??

i would like to add a js file in email content

for that am using  tag

but management center not accepting script word

giving error like script is a prohibited characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restriction has been done to protect the application from XSS attack ( cross site scripting ).

You can try by disabling XSS protection.

Steps

1. Open the following file:

   LOBTools.war/WEB-INF/web.xml

   WebSphere Commerce Developer LOBTools/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

   See Management Center Web application file locations for more information.
2. Search for and remove the following snippet:

   com.ibm.commerce.security.crosssitescriptingprovider
   com.ibm.commerce.foundation.internal.client.security.impl. 
   ClassicCommerceCrossSiteScriptingProviderImpl
3. Save your changes and close the file.
4. Deploy your changes.

But please keep in mind that by doing so you are making your app vulnerable to XSS attack.

Answer (score 1):

There is a black list filter definition in wc-server.xml that is checked on all incoming requests. If the request matches the filter, it gets rejected.

The script html tag is a part of that black list to prevent anyone from injecting potentially malicious content.

Removing this black list isn't recommended.

Also, it's usually not recommended to insert scripts in e-mail as most mail providers will strip them out for security reasons.